# Entity Framework Stumped by GroupBy

Tags: .net, entity-framework

In the code below, `detail` is a list of `{ User, Amount, <other fields> }`, as in

```
var detail = new List<TuitionDetailItem>();
```

What I'd like is for `perMember` to be a list of `{ User, Total }` where the floats are the sums over `Amount` for each `User`.

```
var perMember = detail
    .Where(x => x.ItemType == TuitionDetailItemType.Details)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.User, x.Amount })
    .Select(x => new { x.Key.User, Total = x.Sum(y => y.Amount) })
    .ToList();
```

What I actually get is just a copy of `detail` with no grouping or summing.

Thanks for help!!
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var perMember = detail
    .Where(x => x.ItemType == TuitionDetailItemType.Details)
    .GroupBy(x => x.User)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, Total = x.Sum(y => y.Amount) })
    .ToList();
```

Or better (I think it's cleaner)

```
var perMember = from d in detail
    where d.ItemType == TuitionDetailItemType.Details
    group d by d.User into g
    select new { User = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(d => d.Amount)};
```